# Non mandatory parameter in pentaho report designer

Tags: pentaho

I want to add a non mandatory parameter in pentaho report designer.
i.e. if the parameter is provided the same should be used in where clause else should not be used in the where clause of the query.

Please help me if this is feasible and if yes, then how to do it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the query itself.
In Postgres I use,

```
WHERE resourcename IN (SELECT CASE WHEN(${agent}::text = '' OR ${agent}::text IS NULL) THEN resourcename ELSE ${agent}::text  END)
```

Here `${agent}` is your parameter if they does not select or if left blank (if the display type is a 'Text Box') this query will give you the normal result else it will return what is provided in the parameter.

Comment: I tried this. This does not return any record. I think some thing needs to be defined at parameter level as well.

Comment: What kind of filter you use? drop down or what?